# Angular e2e fails with 'Angular can't be found' because of Redux enhancer?

Tags: angular, redux, angular-e2e, redux-devtools, angular-redux

I have an angular application that is boilerplate, nothing meaningful, literally the 'welcome' template.

I'm trying to run ng e2e but it fails, checking the chrome tab console before it disappears show me the same error I get when I have redux dev tools enabled but I don't have the extension in my browser.

The code in my app.module:

```
export class AppModule {
  constructor(devTools: DevToolsExtension, ngRedux: NgRedux<IAppState>) {
    let enhancers = isDevMode() ? [devTools.enhancer()] : [];
    ngRedux.configureStore(rootReducer, INITIAL_STATE, [], enhancers);
  }
}
```

Is there any way I could make e2e work and also have this enabled or should I just give up on redux dev tools?

Comment: can you post the tests complete file

Comment: @Sajeetharan the test code does not matter on this one. REDUX apps do not work without the dev-tools-extensions installed at all in 'development' mode. So I'm looking at how to disable it while running e2e or running e2e with 'production' settings or making that chrome instance have that redux dev-tools extensions. If I disable the redux part all is good with the tests.